Cannot seem to disable Spring Boot automatic localhost connection attempt
I'm working on a Spring Boot API to connect to a Mongo instance hosted on the Atlas platform; I have tested it locally with the SpringApplication.run process running and, later during debugging, only the main method to speed things up.
package com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi;

import com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config.MongoGeneral;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoGeneral.class);
        MongoClient mongoClient = context.getBean("getSimpleMongoClient", MongoClient.class);
        System.out.println(mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().first());
//      SpringApplication.run(FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}

I have a @Bean defined in a @Configuration file; I had more buildup and teardown going on to configure a MongoTemplate, but I gradually pulled things back to isolate the issue until it's just become a one-line MongoClient.
package com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.config;

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;


@Configuration
public class MongoGeneral extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "flawless-beans";
    }

    @Bean(name = "getSimpleMongoClient")
    MongoClient getSimpleMongoClient() {
        return MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://<myName>:<myPass>@<myHost>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0");
    }

}

The connection is being made; the database listing in the main method returns properly and correctly, and when I return the application start line, it begins properly; however, I get a cluster of socket errors. (The correct dump begins after this.)
C:\Users\matth\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.2\bin\java.exe -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" "-javaagent:C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51181:C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\matth\IdeaProjects\stack\target\classes;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.5\spring-boot-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.5\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.13\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-sync\4.11.2\mongodb-driver-sync-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson\4.11.2\bson-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-core\4.11.2\mongodb-driver-core-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson-record-codec\4.11.2\bson-record-codec-4.11.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-mongodb\4.2.5\spring-data-mongodb-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.1.6\spring-tx-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.6\spring-context-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.6\spring-beans-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.6\spring-expression-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.2.5\spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.13\slf4j-api-2.0.13.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-rest\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-data-rest-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-webmvc\4.2.5\spring-data-rest-webmvc-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-core\4.2.5\spring-data-rest-core-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\atteo\evo-inflector\1.3\evo-inflector-1.3.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.4\jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.4\jackson-core-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.4\jackson-annotations-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-hateoas\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-hateoas-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\hateoas\spring-hateoas\2.2.2\spring-hateoas-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.6\spring-aop-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\plugin\spring-plugin-core\3.0.0\spring-plugin-core-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.2.5\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.20\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.6\spring-web-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.5\micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.5\micrometer-commons-1.12.5.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.6\spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\com\jayway\jsonpath\json-path\2.9.0\json-path-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\net\minidev\json-smart\2.5.1\json-smart-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\net\minidev\accessors-smart\2.5.1\accessors-smart-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\9.6\asm-9.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.6\spring-core-6.1.6.jar;C:\Users\matth\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.6\spring-jcl-6.1.6.jar com.mistermorse.flawlessbeansjavaspringapi.FlawlessBeansJavaSpringApiApplication
15:05:24.405 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-srv-cluster0.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Adding discovered server ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
15:05:24.416 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.client -- MongoClient with metadata {"application": {"name": "Cluster0"}, "driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync", "version": "4.11.2"}, "os": {"type": "Windows", "name": "Windows 11", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "10.0"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/21.0.2+13-58"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=majority, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='matthewharp', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@5b529706, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@63fdab07, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@7b5a12ae]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=cluster0.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net, srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-gtannn-shard-0', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=true, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='Cluster0', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}
15:05:24.463 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-srv-cluster0.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Adding discovered server ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
15:05:24.468 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-srv-cluster0.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Adding discovered server ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
15:05:24.468 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.client -- MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-data", "version": "4.11.2"}, "os": {"type": "Windows", "name": "Windows 11", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "10.0"}, "platform": "Java/Oracle Corporation/21.0.2+13-58"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@5b529706, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@63fdab07, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@7b5a12ae]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}
15:05:24.493 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87797', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.lambda$open$0(SocketStream.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:211)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:153)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:104)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:78)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
15:05:25.160 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
15:05:25.491 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=520917000, setName='atlas-gtannn-shard-0', canonicalAddress=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='availabilityZone', value='use1-az4'}, Tag{name='diskState', value='READY'}, Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}, Tag{name='workloadType', value='OPERATIONAL'}]}, electionId=null, setVersion=28, topologyVersion=TopologyVersion{processId=665a871af2fba807add8c691, counter=4}, lastWriteDate=Sat Jun 01 15:05:25 CDT 2024, lastUpdateTimeNanos=1346683464069900}
15:05:25.491 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=527605200, setName='atlas-gtannn-shard-0', canonicalAddress=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='availabilityZone', value='use1-az6'}, Tag{name='diskState', value='READY'}, Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}, Tag{name='workloadType', value='OPERATIONAL'}]}, electionId=7fffffff000000000000013c, setVersion=28, topologyVersion=TopologyVersion{processId=665a865eb80a41ac18959d8e, counter=6}, lastWriteDate=Sat Jun 01 15:05:25 CDT 2024, lastUpdateTimeNanos=1346683464073600}
15:05:25.491 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=527487300, setName='atlas-gtannn-shard-0', canonicalAddress=ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-02.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-00.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[Tag{name='availabilityZone', value='use1-az1'}, Tag{name='diskState', value='READY'}, Tag{name='nodeType', value='ELECTABLE'}, Tag{name='provider', value='AWS'}, Tag{name='region', value='US_EAST_1'}, Tag{name='workloadType', value='OPERATIONAL'}]}, electionId=null, setVersion=28, topologyVersion=TopologyVersion{processId=665a88a8100c55ad5f0a0d32, counter=3}, lastWriteDate=Sat Jun 01 15:05:25 CDT 2024, lastUpdateTimeNanos=1346683464069900}
15:05:25.493 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87796', description='Cluster0'}-ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Discovered replica set primary ac-tvjqm1m-shard-00-01.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017 with max election id 7fffffff000000000000013c and max set version 28
flawless-beans

Process finished with exit code 0

Right before the socket stack begins, there's the effort to hit a local server; I've haven't configured it, but I know there is some autoconfiguration. That said, I attempted to block it in the exclude clause attached to my application annotation. Also, I made these changes to application.properties.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://<myUser>:<myPass>@<myHost>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0
spring.data.mongodb.database=flawless-beans
spring.data.mongodb.username=<myUser>
spring.data.mongodb.password=<myPass>
spring.data.mongodb.host=<myHost>

And, for completion, here's my POM.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mistermorse</groupId>
    <artifactId>flawless-beans-java-spring-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>flawless-beans-java-spring-api</name>
    <description>A REST API serving data to an app for my favorite local coffee shop.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Am I missing something obvious? Is there another default local check buried deep enough for me to miss?

With a Spring Boot MongoDB Starter application I can connect to a basic Atlas cluster database and access the collection data (I also have a local installation and it runs on default port).

Use a dedicated or Serverless MongoDB Atlas cluster. The free cluster has restrictions.
You also do not need the spring.data.mongodb.* properties because you have deactivated the Mongo auto configurations. The MongoGeneral configuration will be used.


Well, this error seems to be local; I don't understand the benefit of changing the remote target. All the external calls work, unless I'm misunderstanding. Is the local complaint coming from ground level on the server, maybe?

The error you shared contains cluster0.2ahn6zq.mongodb.net and 2ahn6zq.mongodb.net:27017, meaning it's not trying to connect to a local DB.
If you're currently using a free cluster, switching to a paid cluster is worth considering. This could potentially resolve your issue because it worked for me when I encountered this error a few weeks ago.

Well, before the socket stack, I'm getting 15:05:24.493 [cluster-ClusterId{value='665b7f04ac78406106a87797', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster -- Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017. How can it not be a local attempt? And why is it attempting to connect to multiple targets on multiple hosts?

@rainydaymatt You are right; I can see it now. This has made me realise that you created a MongoClient Bean in MongoGeneral instead of overriding the mongoClient() method in AbstractMongoClientConfiguration. Please override the mongoClient() and remove the Bean. This will ensure that only the MongoClient you return in the overridden mongoClient() method exists in the application context.
